# calculating a riemann sum with given user input

Tags: c

> I have to formulate either a right point, left point or mid point Riemann sum from user input for the coefficients, upper and lower limits of the integral and the number of rectangles under the curve. I understand what the right, left and mid point sums mean but I am having trouble putting it into code. I would really appreciate a bit of guidance for how to actually write the functions in the correct syntax for c. For my function I have so far:

```
float getArea(int choice, int final, int initial, int rectangle)
{
  double i = initial;
  float area;
  while(i < final)
  {
    area += final;
  }
  if (choice == 1)
  {
    //left sum
  }
  else if (choice == 2)
  {
    //mid point sum
  }
  else 
  {
    //right sum
  }
  return (area);
}
```

Comment: Did you write the posted code?  Trying to understand the level of assistance needed.

Comment: yes, but i am not sure where to go from here

Comment: Suggest reviewing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods and code needs a _function pointer_, and `x` range passed in too.  Post code that calls `getArea()`, else the post lacks clarity.

Comment: Just a heads up - your while loop will run forever because you aren't incrementing `i`